# WCF alternative for no setting MaxReceivedMessageSize

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, maxreceivedmessagesize

I'm facing a classic issue MaxReceivedMessageSize in a WCF service but setting up this value according 99% of internet's suggestions is not an option for me. The project must be more secure as possible and changing this property we're vulnerable to a DoS attack.

Today the web method returns a large list of a specific object. So, we're thinking if the server could send several chunks of data. Is it possible? What could you recommend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to send in chunks.
Refer - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Amit, using the transermode="stream" is the only way to do that? I already have the list in memory (server side) and my issue is sending this list in chunks. The stream solution seems more complex than I need.

Comment: Yes. It seems complex for your requirement. Are you using InstanceContextMode.PerSession in your service? then you can use paging like behaviour in your call and assemble response at client.http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86007/ways-to-do-WCF-instance-management-Per-call-Per

Comment: Yes, today I'm using PerSession mode, but I don't understand in what it helps... do you mean making many WCF requests while there is data to be sent? How could I split the list<myObject> in a good way? Thanks

Comment: Yes I meant same. Use LINQ or build your own custom logic like paging.

Comment: Amit, I'm going to implement this solution. Thanks a lot for your feedback! :-)